# javaにおいてif文のネストを減らしたい

Tags: java

下記のようなネストされたif文がある場合、深さ1にするうまいやりかたはありますでしょうか？

```
if(a == null){
    if(b == "あああ"){
        実行文
    }
    if(c == "いいい"){
        実行文
    }
}
```

Comment: if(a == null)のときにbやcの比較したいのですか？

Answer (score 5):

後続の処理がなければ、単純に以下のようにreturnしてしまいます

```
if (a != null) {
  return;
}
if (b == "あああ") {
  実行文
}
if (c == "いいい") {
  実行文
}
```

後続の処理がある場合は、do-while文のbreakを使うことでif文のネストを減らせることがあります。

```
do {
  if (a != null) {
    break;
  }
  if (b == "あああ") {
    実行文
  }
  if (c == "いいい") {
    実行文
  }
} while (false);
```

Comment: 参考になりました！ありがとうございます

Answer (score 5):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

ご提示していただいた例はわかりやすいコードだと思います。
私見ですが可読性のためには直さないほうがいいです。

ただ、Javaでの文字列の比較は、例外なくequalsを使ってください。

```
if(a != null){
  if(b.equals("あああ")){
     実行文
   }
　if(c.equals("いいい")){
     実行文
  }
}
```

**&&** でつなげて (a!=null && b.equals("あああ")) のようにすれば一文になりますがあとで読みたくなくなりますのでお勧めはしません。

また、ヌルチェックはどうしても避けたい、変数 **a** が関数の引数などである場合は **@NotNull** アノテーションを用いることでコンパイルチェックで確認できるようになります。確かに最近はこの方向性ですね。

```
public void yourCoolFunction(@NotNull final String a ) {
 if(b.equals("あああ")){
   //Implemetation
 }
 if(c.equals("いいい")){
   //Implemetation
 }
}
```

Comment: 詳しく丁寧に説明していただき、ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 0):

ネストを減らすコード例です。

```
if(a == null && b == "あああ"){
    実行文
}
if(a == null && c == "いいい"){
    実行文
}
```

質問の趣旨から外れますが、文字列の内容が同じであるかを比較するならequalsメソッドを使った方がよいと思います。
`b.equals("あああ")`

Comment: 本当ですね、ご指摘いただきありがとうございます！